# Run a batch file from button click in delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a batch file and an application developed in delphi7. Both are working fine. I want to run the batch file when clicking a button. what can I do for that?

Thanks
Nelson

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) which is declared in ShellAPI.

```
ShellExecute(
    MainForm.Handle,
    'open',
    PChar(scriptfilename),
    PChar(params),
    PChar(workingdirectory),
    SW_SHOW
);
```

Comment: @Nelson Does this answer the question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Can we use CreateProcess instead of SE? how?

Comment: To use `CreateProcess` you'd have to send it `cmd.exe` as the executable, and then whatever arguments are needed to run the script.  Typically that would be `/C scriptfilename.bat`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you mean passing `'cmd.exe /C scriptfilename.bat'` as 'lpCommandLine' I've already tried it.. I'm using [RunDosInMemo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119999/getting-output-from-a-shell-dos-app-into-a-delphi-app/9120103#9120103), it only shows an empty cmd window, and my app stops on `until (Apprunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT)` loop till I close cmd manually, however the command runs OK from Run window. should I change anything in RunDosInMemo?

Comment: @saastn I can't do this in comments to an unrelated question. If you've got a question about the code you have, ask it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var
 exe_start_map:string;
 begin
  exe_start_map:=(ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName));     
   winexec(PChar(exe_start_map+'\yourfile.bat'),sw_show);
 end;
```

you must add ShellApi in uses list