# Java console Input/Output/Error redirection to another (Delphi) application

Tags: java, delphi, delphi-xe6

I am constructing a Command Prompt Process in my Delphi application which is able to interact with the JDB to compile, run and debug a Java application. Cmd input/output/errors are handled through pipelining from the cmd to/from my Delphi application UI.

I want the output of the java program when using 'System.out' / 'System.err' to be directed to a component of my Delphi Application and I want input from my delphi application to be sent to 'System.in' allowing me to form a console in my Delphi UI similar to the console in the Eclipse IDE.

A few thoughts on approaches;

- An obscure flag (I haven't found) in the Java compiler allowing me to redirect
- Using 'System.setOut'/'System.setErr'/'System.setIn' along with a main method in a class which performs this initialization before pointing to the normal main method to run the users code.

NB - I have tried searching through the Eclipse sourcecode to see how they did it but as it is written in Java, I suspect they wouldn't face cross language issues I would face.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting output from a shell/dos app into a Delphi app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119999/getting-output-from-a-shell-dos-app-into-a-delphi-app)

Comment: I have already achieved what your suggested question describes (pipelining), this is regarding where the Java System.in/out/err is going and how to forward it to a Delphi app. Pipelining requires the construction of the process to work as far as I am aware and while I am making the Java application, I have no control over the construction of the Java Console. Furthermore pipelining uses pointers which I don't believe exist in any form in Java.

Comment: The OS already provides all you need. When a process is started you supply the three standard handles.

Comment: The process started by Delphi is the command prompt, the command prompt uses the JDB to compile and execute the java files. I dont think I can use the OS in the way you are describing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. You need two command prompt processes, each constructed with a Read, Write and Error pipe in Delphi.

One of them runs the Java application and is set to wait for a debugger to be attached before executing and the other is for debugging and is attached to the waiting Java application.

This is for the main application; all application console input/output/errors will be handled through this process.

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_shmem,address=DelphiExecutingAppAddress,server=y,suspend=y MyClassFile.java
```

This is for the debugger; all jdb console input/output/errors will be handled through this process (break points, resuming, getting object details).

```
jdb -attach DelphiExecutingAppAddress
```

N.B. Perhaps this is what David was referring to? It looks like it was my mistake when reading the jdb documentation in not finding this on the first work-through. Perhaps this thread may help others.